# johnny-five to arduino >>> serial communication

Tags: javascript, arduino, iot, johnny-five

I am new to johnny-five.js framework (javascript-iot) I would like to do some *"hello world"* in johnny-five by blinking the onboard led at the arduino board and according to some tutorials the board is at default pin 13 and this is the error..

> /home/botkiller/javascript/samplej5/node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:96
>     throw err
>     ^
>
> Error: Could not locate the bindings file. Tried:  →
>   /home/botkiller/javascript/samplej5/node_modules/serialport/build/serialport.node
>   →
>   /home/botkiller/javascript/samplej5/node_modules/serialport/build/Debug/serialport.node
>   →
>   /home/botkiller/javascript/samplej5/node_modules/serialport/build/Release/serialport.node
>   →
>   /home/botkiller/javascript/samplej5/node_modules/serialport/out/Debug/serialport.node
>   →
>   /home/botkiller/javascript/samplej5/node_modules/serialport/Debug/serialport.node
>   →
>   /home/botkiller/javascript/samplej5/node_modules/serialport/out/Release/serialport.node
>   →
>   /home/botkiller/javascript/samplej5/node_modules/serialport/Release/serialport.node
>   →
>   /home/botkiller/javascript/samplej5/node_modules/serialport/build/default/serialport.node
>   →
>   /home/botkiller/javascript/samplej5/node_modules/serialport/compiled/10.0.0/linux/x64/serialport.node
>       at bindings (/home/botkiller/javascript/samplej5/node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:93:9)
>       at Object. (/home/botkiller/javascript/samplej5/node_modules/serialport/lib/bindings/linux.js:2:36)
>       at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:678:30)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:10)
>       at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:589:32)
>       at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:528:12)
>       at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:520:3)
>       at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:626:17)
>       at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
>       at Object. (/home/botkiller/javascript/samplej5/node_modules/serialport/lib/bindings/auto-detect.js:16:22)

I uploaded the standard firmata at my board and install all the dependencies to use the johnny-five to arduino...

Here is my code:

```
const j5 = require('johnny-five');
const board = new j5.Board();

board.on("ready", function(){

    this.pinMode(13, 1);
    this.loop(1000, function (){
        this.digitalWrite(13, 1);
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I downloaded the *npm and node.js* through linuxbrew but I install them **not in root**. Which it is the cause of the error, that the computer can't communicate the device (Arduino) because you have to access the root library of your computer..

hahaha...
PS: Thanks for the grammar check. I am not good really in English.